# Inline VF page not showing data

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce

I've a VF page where I'm using apex detail tag. Now I want to display some data on detail mode which is from another object. For this, I created a VF page with extension controller. I created a new section on layout and embedded this page on the newly created section.However,it's showing the data correctly on preview but not on the actual page?

Any help for this problem?

Comment: Check if you have correct Id passed in URL?

Comment: Actually standard sfdc view is overriden by a vf page. Now, this page has got apex:detail. I removed this override and then I was able to see the data in the inline vf page section. There seems to be some problem with apex:detail which has to be addressed.